# How to create mail function with PHPMailer without using autoload

Tags: php, namespaces, phpmailer

I'm swapping php **mail()** function with **PHPMailer**, in order to use SMTP authentication. I've managed to have it working fine, without using the autoload but using namespace instead:

**test.php**

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
/* The main PHPMailer class. */
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
/* Exception class. */
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
/* SMTP class, needed if you want to use SMTP. */
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$email = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
...
/* Finally send the mail. */
if (!$email->send()) {
    /* PHPMailer error. */
    return $email->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    return "OK";
}
```

As said, all works fine.

But when I try to turn the mailing part into a function, saved in an external file (here, mail.php), I get into trouble, with an "HTTP ERROR 500"; I suppose it's because of the namespace, that is not correctly seen by the `new PHPMailer(TRUE)` statement inside the function.

**test2.php**

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
/* The main PHPMailer class. */
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
/* Exception class. */
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
/* SMTP class, needed if you want to use SMTP. */
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

send_mail($to_address, $from_address, $from_name, $email_subject, $email_body);
```

**mail.php**

```
function send_mail($to_address, $from_address, $from_name, $email_subject, $email_body)
{
    $email = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
    ...
    /* Finally send the mail. */
    if (!$email->send()) {
        /* PHPMailer error. */
        return $email->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

What's the correct way to use the namespace statements inside the function? And/or is there a better way to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

P.S.: the directory structure is as follows:

> test.php
>
> test2.php
>
> inc\mail.php

Comment: Just put the namespaces on the beginning of the file.

Comment: It’s really not clear what you’re doing. You’re making a lot of unnecessary work for yourself by not using composer.

Comment: @Synchro, I have access through CPanel to the website so I doubt I can use Composer, hence my choice.

Comment: @CodiMech25: which file? Could you be more specific? And should I keep them the same, or should they change given the directories structure?

Comment: @Synchro Actually, without composer the final file structure can be much cleaner and the final file size much lower.

Comment: Get a couple of dozen dependencies in there and you’ll end up with a similar file structure to what composer creates, but have no means of controlling it. You can use composer anywhere - run it locally and upload the vendor folder with all your other scripts, just like the docs say.

Answer (score 0):

By the given information you should be able do solve your problem with this solution:

**inc/mail.php**

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

/* The main PHPMailer class. */
require_once '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
/* Exception class. */
require_once '../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
/* SMTP class, needed if you want to use SMTP. */
require_once '../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

function send_mail($to_address, $from_address, $from_name, $email_subject, $email_body)
{
    $email = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
    ...
    /* Finally send the mail. */
    if (!$email->send()) {
        /* PHPMailer error. */
        return $email->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

See, that the namespaces don't change, because namespaces are still the same no matter what file structure you have. But the paths to the included files have to be changed, because your PHP file can have a whatever name and be placed in whatever path that is accessible for you.

So the next step is to include your function to the final file and test it:

**test.php**

```
require_once 'inc/mail.php';

send_mail($to_address, $from_address, $from_name, $email_subject, $email_body);
```

Comment: Thank you, @CodiMech25, for your help. It actually seems there was a problem with the server (assistance hasn't been clearer), now everything works fine.
Btw, the correct path for the 3 classes doesn't need the `../` part, as the mail.php file content gets included in the test.php one.